# Divide by Zero also using *-1

Tags: sql, casting

I'm using this statement to get the unit price of an item

```
(CAST (SalesPrice AS Float) /CAST ( Quantity AS Float)) as [UnitPrice]
```

which works fine on the example I'm starting with, but if I query the entire database I get

> Divide by zero error encountered.

That's my first issue. The second issue when I don't get that error is that the `SalesPrice` was displayed as a negative and I am using `*-1` to show as positive.

Is there a way to do the same with `[UnitPrice]`?

It needs to be displayed as a positive.

Comment: I'm sure `Divide by zero` means that you divide **by** zero, so obviously `Quantitiy` is 0 in some rows.

Comment: Hello Jetta and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions in one question. Also, for any SQL question you should also add a label with the database product you are using (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDb, ...). Each such product has its own dialect, and supports specific functions that others do not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would be getting negative numbers, but use `NULLIF()` to prevent divide-by-zero:

```
CAST(SalesPrice AS Float) / NULLIF(CAST( Quantity AS Float), 0) as [UnitPrice]
```

You can use `ABS()` to get a positive number from any other number.

Comment: When I do that, I get a syntax error near as [UnitPrice.   Also, I thought ABS could only be used for specific numbers, I need the entire column to display as positive

Comment: @Jetta . . . Your syntax error would suggest that parentheses are not balanced, but they are in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` to execute your function conditionally. E.g.,

```
CASE 
    WHEN Quantity = 0 then 0
    ELSE ABS(CAST(SalesPrice AS Float) / CAST(Quantity AS Float))
END as [UnitPrice]
```

Note the `ABS` wrapped around the result of the divide to get a positive number.

Comment: Best have the result be NULL instead of 0, as there is no result to dividing by zero.

Comment: @TT, sure, that's a good option if the query results don't need to be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're casting SalesPrice and Quantity as Float.  Based on their names, they should both be numeric data types of some kind.

```
SELECT ABS(SalesPrice / NULLIF(Quantity, 0)) as [UnitPrice] FROM MyTable;
```

This should turn any Divid by Zero errors into a NULL result.  And it should also make sure that every result is positive.